# Maintain the Process Speed when RT index down?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

We are using Sphinx RT index to listing the results with DISTINCT keyword to query for my site.

If RT index is down, what are the possibilities to maintain the process?

1. Using MySQL without DISTINCT keyword.
2. Any other Possibilities to maintain the same speed like RT index?